# Calculated field for time not always working

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column on a SharePoint list to calculate hour(s) and minute(s) for the time taken to do a training course.

It works for most of the entries, but some that are 1 hour, aren't working and I'm completely stumped!!

Here's my formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>0,CONCATENATE(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)," ",IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>1,"hours","hour")),""),IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])>0,CONCATENATE(" ",MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])," ",IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])>1,"minutes","minute")),""))
```

As you can see here:

[image: SP list]

Please help! Thanks in advance.